# How to convert a .PNG file into a source code that can be stored into mysql and called up via CSS as "png"

Tags: javascript, html, css

On this web site we come to the realization that png files
can be turned into text and stored in mysql and served
via css

`http://www.patternify.com/`

> background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAFUlEQVQImWNggID/DKQArKr/4zUGAMudA/3eohC2AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)repeat;

in other words this alien technology can probably also be used for regular images such as country flags that are png files.

how can i convert all my country flags into text like that so i can store them in mysql.

my operating system is:  centos linux desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to encode the images locally, you can use something like this:

```
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/'.$type.';base64,'.base64_encode($data);
```

You can also use one of a million different online encoders, like this one:

http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

Read up on the limitations of using the base64 encoding in CSS though, I know there are IE6 and IE7 issues, and I think size limitations on IE8 with larger images.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert your PNG files to a Base64 string, then save that string in your DB.

If you only have a few flags (or alot of patience), try here: http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

Otherwise, PHP is your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php